# Knit to html will not execute b/c of error in line 70?

Tags: r, function, sapply

I am trying to create a function that calculates for a numeric vector the difference between the observation and mean of the vector and apply it to an NHANES data frame. This is the suspected code giving an error:

```
library(NHANES)

deviation <- function(x)
  {sd(x) - mean(x)}


sapply(NHANES[1:6,], deviation)
```

And this is the error:

```
Quitting from lines 70-82  
Error in var(if (is.vector(x) || is.factor(x)) x else as.double(x), na.rm = na.rm) : 
  Calling var(x) on a factor x is defunct.
  Use something like 'all(duplicated(x)[-1L])' to test for a constant vector.
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> sapply -> lapply -> FUN -> sd -> var
Execution halted
```

Anyone know what may be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the columns of `NHANES` there are factor columns which you can not apply arithmetic operations. That is the problem.

```r
> str(NHANES[1:6,])
tibble [6 × 76] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ ID              : int [1:6] 51624 51624 51624 51625 51630 51638
 $ SurveyYr        : Factor w/ 2 levels "2009_10","2011_12": 1 1 1 1 1 1
 $ Gender          : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 2 2 2 1 2
 $ Age             : int [1:6] 34 34 34 4 49 9
 $ AgeDecade       : Factor w/ 8 levels " 0-9"," 10-19",..: 4 4 4 1 5 1
...
```

If you do `sapply(NHANES[1:6, c(1,4)], deviation)` for example, it works, since your are applying your function to numeric (actually to integer) data (`ID` and `Age`)